# Unable to import execute function from qiskit library

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

[image]

when I try to run this code, it gives me and error that it was unable to import `execute` from `qiskit` (error pasted below).

```
2 get_ipython().system('pip install --upgrade qiskit qiskit-aer')
      3 import qiskit
----> 4 from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
      5 from qiskit_aer import Aer
      6 from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

ImportError: cannot import name 'execute' from 'qiskit' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/qiskit/__init__.py)
```

I have tried upgrading `qiskit` which didn't work. I have also tried using transpile and the other functions but it changed my code too much and I didn't want that to happen.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execute Function in qskit library is been removed from version 1.00 you can downgrade to version 0.46 and it will Run

Answer (score 5):

One of the great things about qiskit is also one of the challenges, in that it updates quite quickly. The `execute` function has been deprecated since version `o.46.0` ([see notice here](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.46/execute)) and it was removed in the `1.0` release.

If you need to use an older version, such as following along a tutorial or quickstart, you can rollback to earlier releases and use the syntax for that release. For example: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/0.24/execute

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, BasicAer
 
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
 
qc = QuantumCircuit(5, 5)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, range(1, 5))
qc.measure_all()
 
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=4321)
```

Comment: The issue was due to qiskit 1.0 removing execute from its library and I had to downgrade to version 0.46 version. I appreciate your input!

Comment: The note about being able to roll back to follow along with tutorials is important given how many of the existing guides for Qiskit have broken as a result of this change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transpile` in newer version. Refer: [qiskit v1.0 migration guide](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#execute)